# Swift MacApp - merge two images one under another

Tags: swift

I want to merge few images one under another. All I found were examples for iOS UIImage, which is impossible to use on macOS. I believe I should use CIImage for that

```
let img1 = CIImage(contentsOf: filePath);
let img2 = CIImage(contentsOf: filePath2)
print(img1?.extent.height, img1?.extent.width);
print(img2?.extent.height, img2?.extent.width);
```

I can get the width and height of both images, which will be necessary to merge them into one big image but I'm stuck here...

I'm using macOS Big Sur (11.5.2), Swift Language Version: Swift 5

Comment: Something like [Merging/stacking two images with Cocoa/OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18583465/merging-stacking-two-images-with-cocoa-osx) or [Creating a collage by combining an array of images](https://bluelemonbits.com/2019/12/30/creating-a-collage-by-combining-an-array-of-images-macos-ios/)?

Comment: See the list of Core Image filters to find out if there's a filter for that.

Answer (score 0):

@El Tomato, thanks for pointing that CiFilter had such filter! I was able to do what i wanted, get X images of same size and put them one below another (from 1 to X). It's not pretty code, but tried keep it clean.

```
func mergePhotos(imagesCount: Int)
{
    let downloadsPath = FileManager.default.urls(for: .downloadsDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!;
    let directoryURL = downloadsPath.appendingPathComponent("\(directoryPrefix)-\(CurrentDate())");
    let baseImagePath = directoryURL.appendingPathComponent("1.png");
    var imagesPathes = [] as Array;
    
    for imageNumber in 2...imagesCount {
        imagesPathes.append(directoryURL.appendingPathComponent("\(imageNumber).png"));
    }
    
    var baseImage = CIImage(contentsOf: baseImagePath);
    let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIAdditionCompositing")!;
    
    for imagePath in imagesPathes {
        let imageToAppend = CIImage(contentsOf: imagePath as! URL);
        baseImage = baseImage?.transformed(by: CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: imageToAppend?.extent.height ?? 0));
        
        filter.setDefaults();
        filter.setValue(baseImage, forKey: "inputImage");
        filter.setValue(imageToAppend, forKey: "inputBackgroundImage");

        baseImage = filter.outputImage;
    }
    
    let rep = NSCIImageRep(ciImage: baseImage!);
    let finalResult = NSImage(size: rep.size);
    finalResult.addRepresentation(rep);
    
    let imageRep = NSBitmapImageRep(data: finalResult.tiffRepresentation!)
    let pngData = imageRep?.representation(using: NSBitmapImageRep.FileType.png, properties: [:]);
    
    let filePath3 = directoryURL.appendingPathComponent("result.png");
    
    do {
        try pngData?.write(to: filePath3, options: .atomic)
    }
    catch {
        print("mergePhotos catch write: \(error)")
    }
}
```